# Price Selector - Pricing Colums

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add 2 sets of pricing columns onto a website. 1st is for normal pricing for car cleaning with the second being for larger cars with a slightly higher price.

I want two buttons at the top (one for car, one large car) and when either is clicked different articles (pricing columns show)

I have done something similar with a galley, I did this by adding a data filter.

Can I do this for a set of articles?

Example of what I have working for the gallery:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul class="list-unstyled ifbFiltersList d-flex isoFiltersList mb-lg-12 mb-xl-14 fontAlter flex-wrap justify-content-center">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">All</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".washing">Washing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".autoDetail">Auto Detail</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".exterior">Exterior</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".interior">Interior</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".repair">Paint Repair</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 isoCol autoDetail">
  <!-- gPhoColumn -->
  <article class="gPhoColumnGallery position-relative overflow-hidden mb-6">
    <div class="imgWrap position-relative">
      <img src="images/gallery/c2.jpeg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="image description">
      <a href="images/gallery/c2.jpeg" class="icnSearch lightbox position-absolute" data-fancybox="true"><i class="lnr lnr-magnifier"><span class="sr-only">icon</span></i></a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 isoCol exterior">
  <!-- gPhoColumn -->
  <article class="gPhoColumnGallery position-relative overflow-hidden mb-6">
    <div class="imgWrap position-relative">
      <img src="images/gallery/c3.jpeg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="image description">
      <a href="images/gallery/c3.jpeg" class="icnSearch lightbox position-absolute" data-fancybox="true"><i class="lnr lnr-magnifier"><span class="sr-only">icon</span></i></a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is stopping you from applying those same principles from that working gallery implementation, for this use case now?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. I started the snippet, Please make it a [mcve]

Comment: @CBroe The Issue with the data filter I used in the gallery is that by default all elements are shown until filtered. This would result in both pricings being shown at the same time.

Comment: So hide them initially via CSS then, when the page loads? Or hide only one of them, if you want to show the other as the "default".

Comment: Thanks for joining the community! 

To get more answers and interest on this question I would suggest two changes:
    1. Make the title a question about the problem, not a description of the project. "How can I hide/display html on a button press" would be a much better title. 
    2. Include information about the organization of your application and the technologies you use in the project. A question or paragraph with this info is useful to anyone giving an answer. You should mention things like frameworks, code libraries, dev tools, storage solutions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML "onclick" event and "hidden" attribute.

There are countless ways to change what is displayed on a webpage, but this is very simple. No need for filters, galleries, etc; just plain HTML and Javascript.

First add the "onclick" attribute to your button elements and the "hidden" attribute to your article elements. Then, in your script file create two Javascript functions to show/hide your articles. Make sure those functions are referenced correctly by the "onclick" attributes of your buttons and you are set.

*Note you specified buttons and articles, but you can use "onclick" and "hidden" on *any* html element (img, div, a, etc).

Your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="button-container row">
    <button id="car-button" onclick="showCarInfo()">Car</button>
    <button id="large-car-button" onclick="showLargeCarInfo()">Large Car</button>
</div>

<div class="info-container">
    <article id="car-info" hidden>
        <h2>Car information is working</h2>
        <!--All your article stuff-->
    </article>
    <article id="large-car-info" hidden>
        <h2>Large car information is working</h2>
        <!--All your article stuff-->
    </article>
</div>
```

And your Javascript file would have these functions:

```
function showCarInfo() {
    document.getElementById("car-info").hidden = false;
    document.getElementById("large-car-info").hidden = true;
}

function showLargeCarInfo() {
    document.getElementById("car-info").hidden = true;
    document.getElementById("large-car-info").hidden = false;
}
```

Here is a link to a JS fiddle where you can do some testing yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/uv9fpxwr/1/